# Use Shared Object (.so) in a C++ project develop in Windows with Visual Studio for Linux using WSL

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2019, wsl-2

For a task I have I must develop C++ code for Linux but from Windows. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with WSL 2 and the tests I've run worked well, it compile .out/.so/.a and giving me the ability to debug the code as if it was a regular project.
The problem is when I need to link external .so to my project. In regular Windows-VS-c++ development I define the input linker to the directory of the .lib. But in Linux their no .lib (or is their? I'm not familiar with Linux-C++).

In short how do I consume Shared Object (.so) files from another project using Visual Studio 2019 compiling for Linux using WSL 2 ?

Comment: **What kind of C++ code are you developing?** Embedded Linux code controlling an aircraft? web code? How critical is it? Could a bug in your code kill people? **What is the code size** (millions of C++ source code lines like in [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [LibreOffice](https://libreoffice.org/)...) or just a few dozen thousands of C++ lines? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63592191/edit) your question to give more details!

Comment: Did you find a way? Struggle with the same problem

Comment: In the end I moved to an Ubuntu computer with CLion installed, so I'm using CMAKE to link libraries. It's definitely possible with VS on windows with WSL, if you you didn't succeed  it's probably because the linkage is wrong and it would not have worked in  a linux machine either.
In short you need to define the linkage to the library (in the Linux machine, off-course). I think you can also add the libraries in /lib (it's not good practice though but it should work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ask your boss permission to install Linux on your work computer

(e.g. some genuine Linux distribution such as [Debian](https://debian.org/) or [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) in some separate disk partition). **This is -in terms of effort and your time- the *cheapest* route to follow**.

Read of course [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), the [Program Library HowTo](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/), the [C++ dlopen minihowto](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/), the documentation of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), the documentation of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), the documentation of [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/), the documentation of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

Of course, read more about [programming in C++](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html). **C++ is a difficult language** (on both Linux and Windows). Refer to this [website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Read later the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

If you code a *single* C++ translation unit `foo.cc` (you could use [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) to edit it), compile it first into a shared object `foo.so` [using](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) a command `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -fPIC -shared foo.cc -o foo.so` (all warnings, DWARF debug information, position independent code).

If your C++ shared library is built from *several* C++ translation units, learn how to use a [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool such as  [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/). And use it in a terminal emulator on the command line. Be aware of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). Use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [ltrace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html), [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) to understand the dynamic behavior of your or others software.

In some cases, generating parts of your C++ code (e.g. with [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) or [SWIG](https://swig.org/)) is worthwhile. Notice that [Qt](https://qt.io/) is doing so.

### Consider using some cross-platform C++ frameworks such as [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/).

For some projects, writing your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) could be useful. See [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report.

> In short how do I consume Shared Object (.so) files from another project using Visual Studio 2019 compiling for Linux using WSL 2 ?

Don't use [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) (I never used it myself, but according to rumors it is unfit for [cross-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) from Windows to Linux). Perhaps use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (to which I prefer [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), but you might try [gedit](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/), [geany](https://www.geany.org/), [vim](https://vim.org/), [kate](https://kate-editor.org/) etc...)

On Linux, all IDE for C++ programming would run a [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler (and you'll need to understand what compilation command they are running for you). You could also be interested by the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or by [Frama-C++](https://frama-c.com/)

### Take inspiration from *existing* open source C++ projects on Linux

Look on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) - e.g. [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/), [Qt](https://qt.io/), [FLTK](https://fltk.org/), [fish](http://fishshell.com/), [icecream](https://github.com/icecc/icecream)) ... Read also [Linux From Scratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/).

## above all, approach Linux programming with a fresh and open mindset.

**Read about the [*Unix philosophy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy), it is relevant on Linux**. And very different from Microsoft design ideas related to Windows.

I never used Windows (and I am coding since 1974), but my biased opinion is that WSL is targeted for Linux gurus who (sadly for them) have to use Windows. I believe WSL is not targeting Linux newbies.

Comment: I might do that at the end, but I'm willing to giving it a try.

Comment: Interessting. Why do you prefere Visual Code?

Comment: Visual Studio is AFAIK not working on Linux. GNU emacs is. I strongly believe that Linux is developer friendly

Comment: Ok, I thought you were saying not to use it on Windows.I'll try a little more to make it work on windows, but I think I'll eventually do what you said and work on Linux instead,

Comment: **Good luck.** If you have to do cross-compilation from Windows to Linux, prepare yourself to need to read *a lot of documentation* and to build cross-compilers from source code.

Comment: Thanks allot for the fast and well developed answer, and for the documentation. It seems like their is still a lot for me to know

Comment: Please upvote and/or accept my answer if it helps. Otherwise, **improve your question**